# Policy query - iframe app posting to multiple (5) friends wall

Tags: facebook, publishing, policy, promotions

After some advice.

I have a client wishing to have an app which lets them download a voucher to redeem in store but only after they post details of this offer onto 5 friends' walls.

My understanding of current Facebook policy suggests that:

1) Promotions can't require users to take any action on Facebook other than to like the page (likegate);

2) Messages posted to multiple friends at once should be unique and personally initiated - i.e. an app shouldn't bulk post to multiple users. Instead users should share things on their own wall....

Am I correct in this understanding? 
If so, can anyone point me at the relevant facebook policies - can't seem to find them on the site.

Comment: @OffBySome thanks for the 2nd opinion - I'm sure I'm 100% right on the promotions element but currently there doesn't seem to be anything in the policies about my second point.... are you aware of any documented guidance on this on the FB site anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are exactly what I read on the policies page. However to be absolutely sure, you should have your corporate attorney read them and consult with you.

See
http://developers.facebook.com/policy/
and
http://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php

Comment: Thanks for the links - I've read those pages and agree it backs up my 1st assumption. Can't currently find anything to confirm the posting to multiple friends issue... any hints on other links?

Comment: The multiple friends issue is covered in those links as well. But again, you should absolutely have you attorney interpret them.